# How to add an icon to a listview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I made a listview in a fragment. Now I need to add a simple icon to the listview items. The icon must be the same on every item. This will be a simple arrow (imageview).
Is this possible with the listview I made? And if yes, how do I do it?

So like this format:
**My text here** *--space--space--* **>**

---

The code for the fragment:

```
  public class BiblioFragment extends Fragment {

final String[] items = new String[] { "Astma en alcohol", "Astma en huisdieren", "Astma en lichaamsgewicht",
        "Astma en ouder worden", "Astmamedicatie", "Bekende mensen met astma", "Longfunctieonderzoek", "Reizen en vakantie",
   "Sociaal leven", "Weetjes over astma", "Enzovoort", "Enzovoort", "Enzovoort" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biblio, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("TAG", "CLICKED row number: " + arg2);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BiblioDetail.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("welkerij", arg2);
            startActivity(myIntent); 

        }

    });

    return view;

   }
  }
```

My XML for that fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="#ffffff">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use a custom adapter inflate a custom layout.

Comment: you need to use the custom adapter for that see [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/2675669

Comment: Is there no other way? Because that seems very hard to alter.

Comment: @user2883477 its is not hard to alter. it is actually easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreateView`

```
ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),items);   
list.setAdapter(cus);
```

Use a custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String items[];
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView ==null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }
        holder.tv.setText(items[position]) 
            // use holder.iv to set whatever image you want according to the position
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    { 
        ImageView iv;
        TextView tv;
    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Edit:

If you feel this is over kill you can use a compound textview with image on the left and text on the right.

In the above I have used `list_item.xml` which is a custom layout. I inflate that layout in `getView` of custom adapter. I set the text to textview. I have set the default launcher icon to imageview. You can change it though.

I have also used a ViewHolder

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Also check

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: This kinda worked. Only I get 'TextView' on every item. Not Astma en Alcohol for example.

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Quick question: How do I add intent etc. to this like in my openingpost?

Comment: @user2883477 when do you want to start a new activity

Comment: OnClick like in my openingpost. It goes to a new activity in this activity it checks which row it is through Arg2.

Comment: it only shows text and not the image, and the text overlaps the toolbar. please tell me how to solve this issue

Comment: @Annie i suggest you post a new question with your relevant code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Create **ListAdapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private List<Item> items;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {

    super(context, resource, items);

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

    }

    Item p = items.get(position);

    if (p != null) {


        ImageView ICon = ( ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);




        }
    }

    return v;

}
```

In your **Activity**

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

// get data from the table by the ListAdapter
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>);

yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: Can I implement this in my fragment?

Comment: yeah you can implement it in fragment

Comment: This does seem a bit overkill actually. I have everything running simply want to add the same icon in every row. 

Can't I just:
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

Put the Imageview in simple_list_item_1? There has to be a easier solution..

Comment: @user2883477 that is not a over kill. that is how you need to do it. Except you can use compound textview. see my post for complete answer

Comment: @user2883477 posted a snap shot also